# Apache downloading html files instead of serving them, php file working

Tags: apache-2.4

My server is downloading only html files intead of serving them! Php files are served correctly. I've checked apache.conf and the mime type is correctly given :

```
AddType application/x-httpd-php .php
AddType application/x-httpd-phps .phps
AddType application/x-httpd-php7 .php7 .phtml
AddType application/x-httpd-php .html .htm
```

I've checked the file with the inline command : wge --server-response -O and header seems to be ok:

```
    HTTP request sent, awaiting response...
    HTTP/1.1 200 OK
    Date: Sat, 03 Sep 2022 17:22:52 GMT
    Server: Apache/2.4.38
    Last-Modified: Wed, 20 Jul 2022 16:31:05 GMT
    Accept-Ranges: bytes
    Content-Length: 2506
    Keep-Alive: timeout=5, max=100
    Connection: Keep-Alive
    Content-Type: application/x-httpd-php
    Length: 2506 (2.4K) [application/x-httpd-php]
    Saving to: ‘/dev/null’
```

I'm searching for hours but can't find anything :-(

Comment: php fpm 7.4 / apache 2.4 / Debian 11

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You claim html is `application/x-httpd-php`. It isn't. It's `text/html`.

Your browser doesn't know how to display `application/x-httpd-php`; it knows how to display `text/html`. You need to send the correct mime type for the browser to display it. If the browser doesn't know how to display mime type sent by the server, it will default to offering to save the file to disk.

Comment: How to do that?

Comment: I've changed it in the apache2.conf to text/html. But it still download it :

Comment: `HTTP request sent, awaiting response...
      HTTP/1.1 200 OK
      Date: Sun, 04 Sep 2022 17:14:07 GMT
      Server: Apache/2.4.38
      Last-Modified: Wed, 20 Jul 2022 16:31:05 GMT
      Accept-Ranges: bytes
      Content-Length: 2506
      Vary: Accept-Encoding
      Keep-Alive: timeout=5, max=100
      Connection: Keep-Alive
      Content-Type: text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1
    Length: 2506 (2.4K) [text/html]`

Comment: Remove your AddType stanza for html. It should not be needed.

Comment: I removed it, but still downloading!

Comment: Give us a URL we can test with.

Comment: https://space-blogs.com/aspirateur.html

Comment: Seems to work! I thing browser cache was still downloading, I used another browser and it served it! :-) thanks! :-)

Comment: Please mark the answer as accepted using the check mark next to it then :)